# What is the function of [~,n]=size(p) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, size

I've searched on the internet, but I can't figure out what this expression is useful for.

```
function [val]=f_obiectiv(p) % functia obiectiv din problema celor n regine
%{ 
gradul de "neconformitate" a unei permutari: numarul de pozitii distincte de pe tabla 
de sah pentru care reginele plasate in acele pozitii sunt in situatie de atac 
%}

[~,n]=size(p);  

val=0;

for i=1:n
    for j=i+1:n
        if(abs(i-j)==abs(p(i)-p(j)))
            val=val+1;
        end;
    end;
end;

% calitatea permutarii: numarul total de perechi de pozitii (regine) posibile - 
% numarul de perechi "neconforme" 

val=n*(n-1)/2-val;

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official documentation of `size`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html):

> *`[m,n] = size(A)` returns the number of rows and columns when `A` is a matrix.*
>
> `[sz1,...,szN] = size(A)` returns the length of each dimension of `A` separately.

The tilda symbol (`~`) means "ignore this output".

Comment: Although in this case I would suggest to use `n = size(A, 2)`